# Customizing SequelizeJS calls

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

So right now I have been using SequelizeJS for my data access layer and the biggest concern I have with it right now it trying to find a way to custom Sequelize model calls.

For example, lets say that for the model.find() method I want to integrate caching with Redis so that if data is cached in Redis, it skips the normal call to the relational database.  The only way I can find for doing something like this would be:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    firstName: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    middleName: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    lastName: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    email: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    username: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    password: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    superAdminFlag: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    requirePasswordChangeFlag: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    lastPasswordChangeDateTime: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    createdTimestamp: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    updatedTimestamp: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    status: DataTypes.STRING(32)
  }, {
    sequelizeSetup: function(models) {
      User.hasMany(models.OauthToken, {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        through: null
      });
    }
  });

  //create a custom object that links to the Sequelize model object
  var MyUser = Object.create(User);

  //add custom logic to the find() method for this model
  MyUser.find = function(options, queryOptions) {
    console.log('custom logic');
    return User.find(options, queryOptions);
  };

  return MyUser;
};
```

My question is whether or not this is the correct way to customize SequelizeJS model methods and if doing this will cause me any issues (and I mean the model object not instances of model object)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way of doing what you want to do in sequelize, but I'd say that what you are doing looks good, and I can't see it causing any problems.

For validate, create, update, destroy, bulkcreate, bulkupdate and bulkdestroy you can use hooks https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Hooks but those are not implemented for find yet (there as [open feature request though](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1430), where you could voice your support)